# SyntaxError: missing ; before statement on normal statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm not sure why I am getting this code. Basically I want to be able to position my emitter dynamically but when I add  a option to check for position and correct as need be I keep getting this error.

The code added is

```
                    if ( pos == 'right' ) {
                      xcord = width + xcord;
                      console.log("xcord");
                    } elseif ( pos == 'center' ) {
                      xcord = width / 2 + xcord;
                    }
```

Which if removed will not cause an error, but with it, throws the missing `;` statement.

**Note** I have tried this with shorthand var operators as well, still same error.

http://codepen.io/WAS/pen/Ejgsw

Comment: Try putting a space between elseif.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because there's no `elseif` keyword in JavaScript.

It's `else if`, two words.